# Scale Transition of a hyperlink doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I would like to do a scale transition of my image contained in an hyperlink. All this is contained in a div. I wrote something but It doesn't work. I need the image to be an hyperlink because it has to redirect the user to another page.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5b2du6q/1/)

```css
#logoemailcol {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#logoemailcol:hover #logoem {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
  transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

```html
<div id="logoemailcol">
  <a href="" id="logoem" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-icons/2048/email-2048-black.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working as expected because the anchor element is `inline` by default and according to the specification, the element should be a block-level or atomic inline-level element in order for it to be ["transformable"](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element).

Therefore you would need to change the `display` of the element to `inline-block` or `block` in order for it to work as expected. In doing so, the value `inline-block` renders the elements as an [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), and therefore the elements become ["transformable"](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element) by definition.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/7g2dsdf5/)

```css
#logoemailcol {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#logoemailcol:hover #logoem {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}
#logoem {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoemailcol">
  <a href="" id="logoem" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-icons/2048/email-2048-black.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
  </a>
</div>
```

Of course you could also apply the transformation to the parent element since it is `block` level, however I am just providing a reason as to *why* it wasn't working for the anchor element.

For reference:

> [**CSS Transforms Module Level 1 - Terminology - Transformable Element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element)
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a [block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-level) or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose [display property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform.

Answer (score 1):

You want to scale and transition the image.

```css
#logoemailcol{
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#logoem img {
  transition: all 0.5s;  
}

#logoemailcol:hover #logoem img{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
  transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

```html
<div id="logoemailcol">
   <a href="" id="logoem" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-icons/2048/email-2048-black.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;"></a>
</div>
```